# Why does spacing and font weight differ on Flutter iOS and Flutter web?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter app I want to deploy to both web and iOS. Here is my password recovery screen on iOS:

[image]

...and here is the same screen on web:

[image]

You'll notice that the spacing between the buttons is markedly different on the two platforms, as is the font weight for the top text.

Web aligns correctly with the values I've entered. So why is iOS adding more spacing between the buttons? And why is the font weight on iOS so much heavier?

The same issue has been reported [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/70217), but the one proposed solution doesn't work for me.